# JMeter - pass value as String

Tags: javascript, parameters, jmeter

I'm using `JMeter` to get data from an HTTP call and use it to make another HTTP call. I correctly get my data from the first call, then I use a `JSR223 PostProcessor with Javascript` to save it with the following statement:

```
var processId = vars.get("processId");
vars.put("processId", processId);
```

It works, but the problem is that the ID is savedas a number, but I need it as a String to pass it inside the JSON of the second HTTP call. I tried:

```
var processId = vars.get("processId")+"";
```

But still is a number. How can I achieve this? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSR223 Sampler/PreProcessor/Post Processor for this purpose. Set the following property in JSR223. Declare the variable as String.

```
Language = groovy
```

[image]

[image]

After that you can use vars.put() to set it to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to go for scripting in order to pass the data between requests, you can just use `${processId}` where required (i.e. in second HTTP Sampler) and it will be resolved. In fact your script is now doing nothing but consuming resources in order to call [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn) interpreter just to overwrite JMeter Variable value with itself.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy language in JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as [Groovy scripts can be compiled into bytecode and cached](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) to avoid re-processing each time the script is being called.
3. Using [`vars.put()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [`vars.get()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-) functions expects and returns the variable value in [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) form, if you need to operate different types - use [`vars.putObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) and [`vars.getObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-) instead